# Compiling C in Java time interval definition

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, runtime, runtime-error, runtime.exec

I would like to run in Java with the Runtime's exec() method a C program. The Java code is the following:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(command);
process.waitFor();
```

How can I define in this case the compiled C program's running time? I mean, if I can set a time interval and if the code hadn't finished running in that interval, to give back a Time limit exceeded error?

Comment: What matters is that the program is some executable. It could be compiled from *C*, *C++*, *Go* or from *Ocaml* source code; that don't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should better think in terms of multi threaded programming here.
Once you've started to execute the program outside the JVM you can't really tell from Java 'stop executing this program'...

So you should probably run the code you've presented here in a separate thread and use

`Object.wait(long milliseconds)`

to wait for the results of this thread.
if you didn't get the result proceed your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (on Linux or Posix systems) the shell [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) builtin (which interfaces the [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) syscall) inside your `command`, e.g. put something like `ulimit -t 120; yourprogram and arguments` inside.

This would only limit CPU time; if `yourprogram` is infinitely sleeping or blocked on some input it won't help.

[Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11306241/841108) suggesting a multi-threaded approach is probably better. But mine is really limiting resources.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'm trying now all of them, and give you a feedback about the best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time to understand what you would like to achieve, but here goes my suggestion - 
A. Have  your code snippet executed in another thread , let's say the Runnable implementation will look like: 
public class ProcessExecutor implements Runnable {

private String command;

public ProcessExecutor(String command) {
      this.command = command;
   }

public void run() {
      Runtime runtime  = RUntime.getRuntime();
      Process process = runtime.exec(command);
      ProcessManager.getInstance().add(process);
      process.waitFor();
   }
}

ProcessManager is a synchronized singletone collection for tracking process execution that you will develop. 
It can be a map, based on process ID, that will hold as value the process itself, and information on start time and the last check time. 
You should use the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to run a scheduled task that will periodically check that status of the executed processes. For each process it can manage the last check time, and if lastCheckTime - startTime exceeds a certain interval it should state there is an error, and maybe destroy the process using the [destroy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29) method/